# Invalid Token in asp dot net core web apis 6.0

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am working with asp dot net core web apis 6.0 I am using JWT token with the help of authorize attribute. But when I try to hit the authorized controller I get an invalid token error.

[image: This is my program.cs class]

[image: This is my protected controller]

[image: Packages Version i am using]

Comment: did you append jwt token to header of your request

Comment: @afshar003 yes when I am hitting protected route I am appending token in the request header

Comment: I have successfully resolved the issue. It turns out that in the latest version of Postman, there's no need to include the 'Bearer' keyword when entering the token. This was the root cause of the 'invalid token' error I was encountering.

Answer (score 0):

you can check these steps;

1. **Middleware Order**: The JWT authentication middleware must come before any authorization middleware. The order should look something like this:

   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();
2. **Correct Token Sent**: When making requests, ensure you're sending the correct token in the Authorization header of your HTTP request. The header should look like `Authorization: Bearer <your-token>`.

Answer (score 0):

Working Sample.
TestController.cs

```
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("GetToken")]    
        public string CreateAccessToken()
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Tom"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "Tom@gmail.com")
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CJKFOGk-9E0aI8Gv09mD-8utzSyLQx_yrJKi1fXc6Y7CeYszLzcmMA2C0_Ej3K7BQdsCW9zoqW3a-5L1ZNRytFC0BeA6dZLsCjoTrFoI9guwvEmJ0gbN9yHQ0fDYbkwGUyJbP6eNEzKbWHMarSx7RWGKaGsxy0qguEMSO3OUWU8"));
            var jwtInfo = new JwtSecurityToken(                  
                    issuer: "localhost",
                    audience: "audience1",
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4)),
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                    );
            var Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtInfo);
            return Token;
        }

        [HttpGet("api")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
        public string Test()
        {
            return "You have pass the bearer";
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                     .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                     {
                         //options.Authority = "localhost";

                         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                         {          
                             ValidIssuer="localhost",
                             ValidateAudience = false,
                             IssuerSigningKey= new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CJKFOGk-9E0aI8Gv09mD-8utzSyLQx_yrJKi1fXc6Y7CeYszLzcmMA2C0_Ej3K7BQdsCW9zoqW3a-5L1ZNRytFC0BeA6dZLsCjoTrFoI9guwvEmJ0gbN9yHQ0fDYbkwGUyJbP6eNEzKbWHMarSx7RWGKaGsxy0qguEMSO3OUWU8"))
                     };
                     });
```

Postman
GetToken
[image]
Hit protected API
[image]